# XGBoost classifier returns negative prediction after defining 'objective':'binary:logistic'

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

***Issue***

I am trying to use the XGBoost classifier and define a custom matric that uses f-beta-score but I am getting negative predicted values returned to the custom function and after np.round I ended up getting three values ***[-1,0,1]***

***Question***

How do I solve this issue, as I want to know about the f_beta_score during the training eval?

**Function of Custom performance matrics**

```
def fbeta_func(y_predicted, y_true):
  f = fbeta_score(list(y_test),np.round(y_predicted),beta=0.5)
  return 'f_beta', f
```

And then I am calling this function in the **fit function**:

```
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
clf = XGBClassifier(**param)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train,
    eval_set=[(X_test, y_test)],
    eval_metric=fbeta_func,
    verbose=True)
```

Here are the **parameters:**

[image]

Comment: I too am getting negative predictions passed to a custom metric function with objective='binary:logistic' :(

Comment: @JoãoBravo you got any solutions?

Comment: I my post about it, someone suggested the custom metric function was receiving the values of the logit function, but I am not convinced from what the XGBoost tutorials say. [Check it here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/111431/xgbclassifiers-predictions-are-not-probabilities-with-objective-binarylogisti).